# Multiple definition of logger-errors

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two test files, one old and one new. When I test the new file I get the following message:

```
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/86258799/loggerthread_nomain.o: In function `log':
c:/repos/trunk/logging/impl/../include/Logger.h:71: multiple definition of `logger'
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/tests/tests/loggingsimpletest.o:C:\repos\trunk\logging/tests/../include/Logger.h:71
: first defined here

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/tests/TestFiles/f1] Error 1
make: *** [.build-tests-impl] Error 2
```

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please show us the command you use to compile the code, and definition of `logger`.

Comment: As far as the command is considered i right clicked on the test file and click on test,the definition of the logger is in logger class

Comment: You have multiple definitions in there. This might be caused by multiple inclusions of a header. You need to determine which source-file causes the error, and then show us the relevant part of that source file. We cannot help without that information. Please don't just post all files - you can use trial and error to determine which file actually causes the error.

Comment: So this means if i need to include a header file as #include "FileLogger.h",the error arises if i have included this for 2 times in the same source file if that is the case , i have checked this is not done anywhere although when i test any of the test files out of two i got these errors,although i do have have source files which i which similiar header files like the one "logger.h" is included

Comment: Multiple inclusion can happen indirectly. If `A.h` includes `B.h`, and `A.cpp` includes both, you have included `A.h` twice. To narrow down the error try to eliminate includes until the error goes away.

Comment: Yes this is somehow the case is meanwhile could you please let me know whether two test files run simultaneously when i test only a single file, could that be a case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your Logger.h header file to prevent multiple inclusion.

You may also be defining the same class in both the header and source file. You should only define it in once place or the other (generally the header file).